# Add In-Text Tags to Jekyll Site

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am just wondering if it is possible to write tags outside of front matter in Jekyll. I know generally it is not, but I would really like to be able to add some tags as I am writing posts. I have done some research and think this might be possible with plugins, but have not written one before and am a little worried about going down that road and finding that it's not possible...

This would look something like

```
---
layout: post
categories: Marx
--- 
In this chapter of Marx, we learn about commodity fetishism, which can be described below. 
[defs](commodity fetishism - the perception of the social relationships involved in production as economic relationships among the money and commodities exchanged in market trade)
```

With the hope that, at some point just as I can now write

```
(% for categories in site.posts %)
```

I could write

```
(% for defs in site.posts %)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add an example of what you are trying and what is the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my goal was to add in-line tags and then to be able to call these tags on separate pages. I eventually was able to do this with a combination of Jekyll and Python. I save all of my raw posts in a "topublish" folder. At the beginning of each post I include a front matter tag defs_used: so:

```
---
layout: post
title:  xxxx
date:   2017-07-11 17:50:00
categories: ['Reading Notes']
defs_used:

---
```

As I am taking notes and come across a definition I do this

```
In this chapter of Marx, we learn about commodity fetishism, which can be described below. 
<def>commodity fetishism: the perception of the social relationships involved 
in production as economic relationships among the money and commodities 
exchanged in market trade</def>
```

Once I am finished I run a python script to search for definitions and write them into the defs_used: category. The script saves the updated posts in the '_posts' folder:

```
import os
import re
files = [f for f in os.listdir("_topublish") if f.endswith('.markdown')]
for posts in files:
    print(posts)
with open("_topublish/"+posts,"r") as post1:
    post = post1.read()
    defs = re.findall("<def>(.*?)</def>",post)
    replacement = "defs_used:\n"
    for definition in defs:
        replacement = replacement+"\n    "+definition

    newpost = post.replace("defs_used:\n",replacement)
    newname = posts.replace('.markdown','-defs.markdown')
    print newpost
    with open("_posts/"+newname,'w') as w:
       w.write(newpost)
```

This collects all of the definitions and puts them into the tags like this:

```
---
layout: post
title:  xxxx
date:   2017-07-11 17:50:00
categories: ['Reading Notes']
defs_used:
    commodity fetishism: the perception of the social relationships involved in production as economic relationships among the money and commodities exchanged in market trade
---
```

On a new page I create a table of definitions like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Link</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Term</th>
  <th>Definition</th>
  </tr>
    {% for post in site.posts %}
      {% for def in post.defs_used %}
      <tr>
      <th>Access here[{{post.url}}]</th>
      <th>{{ post.title}}</th>
      <th>{{ post.date}}</th>
      <th>{{ def[0] }}</th>
      <th>{{ def[1] }}</th>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The only problem I continue to have is that the links back to the page don't work because the markdown doesn't function quite right in an HTML style table. Other than that, this works out great. I have a running list of all definitions from all of my reading notes, and just have to run "python defs.py" before publishing! So there is the answer to my own question...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible using Jekyll.

You basically pla to write definitions or anchors in Jekyll and then putting those somewhere at some point.

But it would mean, you have to generate all pages, then regenerate them and put all the definitions you have collected in the right places.

You need to have that defs handy already before generation time so you can put them at the right place when you generate the pages.

One solution could be, to put these to the front matter (I know, you said you don't want to, but...). The front matter can be evaluated by a plugin BEFORE the generation starts.

In example:

```
--
defs_used:
   key: value
   key: value
...
```

And in the plugin:

```
class Generator < Jekyll::Generator
    def generate(site)
      site.data['defs'] = Array.new
      site.posts.docs.each do |p|
         p.data['defs'].each do |def|
           site.data['defs'].unshift(def)    
...
```

(untested, but I hope you get the point)

Once this is done, you can access the defs from where ever you like.

Without that kind of plugin, it will be hard. As far as I know Tags will be created on call, so you cannot put a state into them. And I would hesitate to access the site from a tag - this will be a horrible mess to maintain and debug.

Good luck!